# Sticky nav bar with native JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

How would I make a sticky nav bar without using jQuery?

I want to do something like:

```
if (scrollheight == x)

navbar.addclass "sticky"
```

Comment: why not make your nav bar position:fixed? in css? instead of js?

Comment: you can `navbar.className = 'sticky'` or `navbar.classList.add('sticky')` - only on modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

I have recently worked on sticky sidebar nav using EmberJS.

Anyway at the end I decided to extract the solution into vanilla javascript based pen as it seems sticky navigation is pretty common feature.

You can see it here: http://codepen.io/moubi/pen/ALpmwy

Github project: https://github.com/moubi/sticky-nav

**Here is the js code I am using for the functionality:**

```
// https://github.com/moubi/sticky-nav

const NAV_OFFSET = 30;

class StickyNav {
  constructor() {
    this.el = null;
    this.anchor = null;
    this.removedScrollClass = '';

    this.events();
  }

  didRender() {
    this.el = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
    this.anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-anchor')[0];
    this.removedScrollClass = this.el.className;

    this.onResize();
  }

  onResize() {
    var { paddingLeft, paddingRight } = window.getComputedStyle(this.el.parentNode),
      parentWidth = this.el.parentNode.offsetWidth - parseInt(paddingLeft) - parseInt(paddingRight);

    this.el.style.width = `${parentWidth}px`;
  }

  onScroll() {
    var scroll = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop),
      topOffset = this.anchor.offsetTop - NAV_OFFSET;

    if (this.el.className.indexOf('scroll') != -1) {
      if (scroll <= topOffset) {
        this.el.className = this.removedScrollClass;
      }

    } else if (scroll >= topOffset) {
      this.el.className += ' scroll';
    }
  }

  events() {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => { this.didRender(); });
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => { this.onScroll(); });
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => { this.onResize(); });
  }
}

new StickyNav();
```

This solution should work for top nav bar as well with some minor adjustments. 
In the code I am actually adding `scroll` class, but in your case it should be `sticky` - at the end "sticky" sounds more reasonable.